# Emitting a class overriding two interface methods with same name

Tags: c#, .net, reflection.emit

I'm trying to use Reflection.Emit to emit a class that will inherit from multiple interfaces at run-time, and I cannot know which interfaces ahead of time.

As per [MSDN/TypeBuilder.DefineMethodOverride](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.typebuilder.definemethodoverride.aspx):

> To override a method of a base class or to implement a method of an
>   interface, simply emit a method with the same name and signature as
>   the method to be overridden or implemented

Here's my code that overrides an interface method:

```
private void OverrideMethod(TypeBuilder typeBuilder, 
                            Type interfaceToOverride,
                            MethodInfo methodToOverride)
{
    // Create the method stub
    MethodBuilder methodBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineMethod(
        methodToOverride.Name,
        MethodAttributes.Public
        | MethodAttributes.HideBySig
        | MethodAttributes.NewSlot
        | MethodAttributes.Virtual
        | MethodAttributes.Final,
        CallingConventions.HasThis,
        methodToOverride.ReturnType,
        methodToOverride.GetParameters().Select(p => p.ParameterType).ToArray()
    );

    // Implement the overriding method
    ILGenerator il = methodBuilder.GetILGenerator();

    // ... a bunch of calls to il.Emit ...

    // Return 
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
}
```

This works, except when I inherit from two interfaces who both have a method with the same name. Obviously this is because I'm not giving a fully-qualified name for the method.  I'm not sure how to do this properly.

Changing `methodToOverride.Name` to `interfaceToOverride.FullName + "." + methodToOverride.Name` did not work: I get an error when emitting, "TypeLoadException: class does not have implementation.

Using `DefineMethodOverride` partially worked, but for some reason did not when I tested it against nested interfaces. Also, the documentation linked above explicitly says not to do this.

What's the right approach to get around this issue?

Comment: Reading the [MSDN page for `DefineMethodOverride`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.typebuilder.definemethodoverride%28VS.95%29.aspx) seems to indicate that that _is_ the mechanism you need to use to define explicitly declared interface implementations. Perhaps you can post the code you used to define it and call it in your tests?

Comment: @Chris: Maybe I'm misunderstanding what they mean by "Do not use this method to emit method overrides or interface implementations." (The first sentence in the link.)  That sounds like exactly what I'm trying to do here.

Comment: @notfed - I believe they mean that you shouldn't use `DefineMethodOverride` to define implicit interface implementations.  However, I believe that it is the only way to create an interface implementation where the name of the method differs from the name of the method used by the interface.

Comment: Ah! It was not working for nested classes because...........my tests were bad! All good now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way to do this is to define a method named `<InterfaceName>.<MethodName>` and then call [`TypeBuilder.DefineMethodOverride`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.typebuilder.definemethodoverride.aspx).

> The DefineMethodOverride method is used *when a method body and a
>   method declaration have different names*.

In your case, method body name is `<InterfaceName>.<MethodName>`, while method declaration name is `<MethodName>`. So it's fine to use [`TypeBuilder.DefineMethodOverride`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.typebuilder.definemethodoverride.aspx).

**Example usage**:

```
private void OverrideMethod(TypeBuilder typeBuilder, 
                            Type interfaceToOverride,
                            MethodInfo methodToOverride)
{
    // Create the method stub
    MethodBuilder methodBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineMethod(
        /* Change method name here */
        string.Format("{0}.{1}", interfaceToOverride.FullName,
            methodToOverride.Name),
        MethodAttributes.Public
        | MethodAttributes.HideBySig
        | MethodAttributes.NewSlot
        | MethodAttributes.Virtual
        | MethodAttributes.Final,
        CallingConventions.HasThis,
        methodToOverride.ReturnType,
        methodToOverride.GetParameters().Select(p => p.ParameterType).ToArray()
    );

    // Implement the overriding method
    ILGenerator il = methodBuilder.GetILGenerator();

    // ... a bunch of calls to il.Emit ...

    // Return 
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

    // And define a methodimpl, which consists of a pair of metadata tokens.
    // One token points to an implementation, and the other token points
    // to a declaration that the body implements
    typeBuilder.DefineMethodOverride(methodBuilder, methodToOverride);
}
```

**Note**

Actually, you can define your method (using `TypeBuilder.DefineMethod`) with *any* name. But it should differ from `<MethodName>` and you *must* call [`TypeBuilder.DefineMethodOverride`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.typebuilder.definemethodoverride.aspx) to "link" method body with method declaration.